# Prove that the Jacobian matrix is the matrix representation of the derivative. Non-ambiguous statement for "is the matrix representation of"?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that the matrix representation of the derivative is the jacobian matrix, but I can't find a non-ambiguous statement to complete the proof. I've tried the following proof technique: I'm looking to establish the identity between the $j$th partial derivative of $f(\vec a)$ designated by $f'(\vec a)(\vec e_j)$ and the $j$th column of the Jacobian matrix, but I still can't complete the proof. I don't know if I'm making a mistake or if I'm lacking linear algebra here somewhere. Here's the argument:

Let $\{ e_1, ..., e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, and suppose $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$. Therefore, we have $$\lim \limits_{\vec h \to \vec 0} \frac{f(\vec a + \vec h) - f(\vec a) - f'(\vec a)(\vec h)}{||\vec h||} =0$$
If we let $\vec h = t\vec e_j$ for any $j = 1, ..., n$ and do some manipulations, we can arrive at
$$f'(\vec a)(\vec e_j) = \lim \limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(\vec a + t\vec e_j) - f(\vec a)}{t}$$

Which is the definition of the $j$th partial derivative of $f(\vec a)$, from which we can conclude that $f'(\vec a)(\vec e_j)$ *is* the $j$th partial derivative of $f(\vec a)$. **This where I'm stuck**.

What would be a meaningful statement establishing "the matrix representation of the derivative is the jacobian matrix"? I'm thinking that if I can say: the $j$th column of the jacobian is identical to $f'(\vec a)(\vec e_j)$, this could be acceptable, but what exactly is the definition of identity that I'm looking for here? It seems to me that the statement "$f'(\vec a)(\vec e_j)$ is identical to the $j$th column of the Jacobian matrix" is an ambiguous statement. To give an example the element $a_{ij}$ of the Jacobian is not identical to the ith component of the vector $f'(\vec a)(\vec e_j)$, the former being a real number and the latter being a vector.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $f'(a)$ is a linear map $f'(a) \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. You want to find the matrix representation of $f'(a)$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. This will indeed be the Jacboian, and you are on the right track to proving this.

Comment: @Mason (edited) right, thanks! but how would I go about showing identity in this case? I can't seem to get around the ambiguity of "is a matrix representation of". For instance, how could I establish an identity between the matrix representation $f'(\vec a)$ and the set of all the partial derivatives $f'(\vec a)(\vec e_j)$?

Comment: You have to understand what matrix representation means and then verify that the Jacobian is the matrix representation of $f'(a)$. In this case it is enough to show that if $(a_{ij})$ denotes the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $a$, then $\langle f'(a)e_j, e_i \rangle = a_{ij}$.

Comment: @Mason thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really are missing is an understanding of what is the derivative in the multivariable setting, and perhaps the single variable setting as well.

The derivative of a function at a point (in which it is derivable, of course), is the linear operator "best approximating" (in some sense) the difference between the value of the function at the point of evaluation minus the value of the function at the point of derivation.

This is characterized by the expression $\dfrac{f(x + te_j) - f(x)}{t}$. The value of $f$ is a vector, say, in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let's go back to the single variable case. The value of $\dfrac{f_i(x + te_j) - f_i(x)}{t}$ is the slope of the line connecting the point $(x,f_i(x))$ with the point $(x + t,f_i(x + te_j))$. You would then say that the function $f_i(x + te_j)$, as a function of $t$, has the derivative $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f_i(x + te_j) - f_i(x)}{t}$, which is to say that the slope of the tangent at $t=0$ is that value. Let's denote it by $J_{i,j}(x)$. If we think of $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x + te_j) - f(x)}{t}$ as an $m$-tuple of derivatives of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then it becomes clear that in the same sense in which $\dfrac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j}t$ is a good linear approximation to the function $f_i(x + te_j) - f_i(x)$, which is to say that
$$f_i(x + te_j) - f_i(x) \approx \dfrac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j}t,$$
the vector $f(x + te_j) - f(x)$ is similarly well approximated by the linear function $\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}t$, which is the $j$'th column of our supposed Jacobian matrix.

Extending this to the other varialbes, we obtain different "vectors", so that if we are interested in approximating the function $f$ linearly at the point $x$, we may consider a set of steps $t_j$ in each direction, and seek to approximate
$f(x + t_1x_1 + t_2x_2 + ... + t_nx_n) - f(x)$, if, say, $f$ had a domain such as $\mathbb{R}^n$ for example. Since we approximate $f$ as a linear operator, it is enough to know how it acts on a basis, which we already know due to our previous calculation! Extending this by linearity, we may write, for example
$$f(x + t_1x_1 + t_2x_2 + ... + t_nx_n) - f(x) \approx f(x + t_1x_1 + ... + t_{n-1}x_{n-1} + t_nx_n) - f(x + t_1x_1 + ... + t_{n-1}x_{n-1}) + f(x + t_1x_1 + ... + t_{n-1}x_{n-1}) - f(x)\approx f(x + t_1x_1 + ... + t_{n-1}x_{n-1}) - f(x) + \dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_n}t_n$$
which collapses into
$$\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1}t_1 + ... + \dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_n}t_n$$
Since $\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}$ is by definition the $j$'th column of the Jacobian, since multiplication on the right is equivalent to column manipulations, where the first entry meets the first column, the second entry meets the second column and so forth, writing $\vec{t}$ for the column vector of $t$ entries, we realized the identity
$$f(x + t_1e_1 + ... + t_ne_n) - f(x) \approx J(x)\cdot \vec{t}$$
which is precisely an approximation of the function $f(x + t_1e_1 + ... + t_ne_n) - f(x)$ by a linear operator. That $f$ has the property that it is linearly approximated (in a suitable sense) by its Jacobian is in fact the definition of differentiability!

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: This link also provides a fairly straightward proof - https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~jinto/Derivative%20and%20Jacobian%20matrix%20L03.pdf